# slideToggle function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to create a function to open the last echoes. I do not really understand how I can do it without adding seven times. NEXT ()

When I click the `onopen_close` button I need open a `pelet_div`.

This is my HTML:

```
            <div class="table_tr ">
                <div class="w30 first"><input type="button" value="" class="open_close"/></div>
                <div class="w120 first"><span>Medicid MI</span></div>
                <div class="w120"><span>Income</span></div>
                <div class="w120"><span>10/03/2014</span></div>
                <div class="w170"><span>Payment-Cash</span></div>
                <div class="w120"><span>-2616.00</span></div>
                <div class="w120"><span> 10/ 000073</span></div>
                <div class="w120"><span>12/004155</span></div>

                <div class="pelet_div">

                </div>
            </div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pelet_div").hide();
     $(".open_close").show().click(function () {
         clickedComponent = $(this);
         $(this).closest('div').next().slideToggle(function(){
             if($(this).is(':visible'))
                 clickedComponent.css("background-position","left top");
             else
                 clickedComponent.css("background-position","left -14px");  
         });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using siblings with a selector seem to do the trick :

```
$(this).closest('div').siblings('.pelet_div').slideToggle(...)
```